# Bootstrap validation with ASP.NET framework 4.5 Web Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have some ASP.NET aspx form that contains:

```html
<div class="form-group input-group" runat="server" id="div_last_name">
    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" CssClass="form-control required" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group input-group" runat="server" id="div_email" >
    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control required" runat="server"  placeholder="E-Mail"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

I want to validate using this jQuery, but I don't know how to use it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#btnRegister_Click").click(function () {

        var error = 0;

        $('input.required').each(function (i, item) {
            if ($(item).val() == '') {
                $(item).addClass('form-control has-error');
                error = 1;
            }
            else {
                $(item).removeClass('form-control has-error');
            }
        });

        if (error) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    var min_height = jQuery(window).height();
    jQuery('div.col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3').css('min-height', min_height);
    jQuery('div.col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3').css('line-height', min_height + 'px');

    $(".inner", ".boxed").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where it says:

```
$("#btnRegister_Click")
```

You need to replace that with the name of your button. If it's a regular HTML button, just use the name of your button like:

```
$("#nameofbutton")
```

If you using Server Control, you need to get the unique client id of the button. You can do that using:

```
$('#<%= nameofbutton.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: in this section  $('input.required').each(function (i, item) what to type instead of input.required?